# SQL Function in PHP Call

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

This may be an odd question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. I have a function in my database and I want to know if I can do the following:

```
$cheese = "cheese";
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (CAP_FIRST('$cheese'))";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

A simple yes or no is enough. Thanks.

Just going to keep this short, I don't think I missed any vital information.

Comment: Why can't you just use the PHP function `strtoupper`

Comment: Yes, sure. If `CAP_FIRST` is a defined function in MySQL, yes. Why not try it?

Comment: Just try to execute, see if that work. why is the need of asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you cann use any function that is present in your database. The sql statement is not parsed or altered in any way before it is send to the database.